# How do I add white label functionality to a Unity mobile application?

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, network-programming, white-labelling

I was recently approached by a family member of a friend to develop a financial app they plan to use with the businesses he works with. When I was discussing the project and what he was expecting, it is absolutely critical that the application can be White Labeled by the businesses that he works with.

I have spent all day trying to find an answer on how to program such a thing myself, but I am struggling to find an actual explanation or guide. I am using Unity because it is the program I am familiar with since my focus is game design.

Comment: Hey did my answer work for you? If so do not forget to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an app then you should not use Unity for it. Unity's main focus is to make games not apps.

You have a few choices:

1. Flutter but you must learn Dart language.
2. React Native but you must learn JS.
3. Native app but you must code for both android and IOS.
4. WebView and Webapp but you should learn web design.

Since you know C# from Unity you may jump to Java and develop Android applications, but IOS part will be harder.

I do not recommend you to use Unity for the application part it will be hard and under the performant application. Since it is app not a game, it will be hard to maintain, develop and it probably drain device's battery quite fast.

Comment: Of course, a game _is_ an application. It is certainly not a financial application, and it needs a different framework, but a game is still an application.

Comment: Its not the ideal program obviously. But its the one that I know. Would I be able to add White Label functionality to a Unity designed mobile app? I had the idea of a master unity program that builds the client version with the injected images and information for the white label, but I don't know if a Unity build can build other builds.